# Sci-fi Book Help - A rogue among the stars whose name was Cat

Tags: story-identification

I remember I once read 1 or 2 books in this series but I am unable to find any reference to them now. I apologize for how vague this is going to be.

The main characters name was Cat (or Kat)(or he was a cat).

It was not set on earth.

One of the books was about a mining colony. The only specific detail that I remember is that the main character was given an earring with an emerald bead which was very significant. (almost a status symbol)

Publication date: Pre-2000

Comment: Was the character a telepath (or psion)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I believe this is the [Cat Series by Joan Vinge](https://www.goodreads.com/series/40790-cat) (No clue why it has books not part of the series listed there, but the series is 3 books).

It follows the main character named "Cat" who is half-human and has telepathic powers. He starts off-Earth and is dragged back.

The cover of the second book seems to highlight an earring.

[image]

[This excerpt](http://bookre.org/reader?file=293873) mentions an earring which seems to be a relic of some sort.

> “Your ear’s bloody,” she said. I touched it with my fingers, remembering, feeling the earring. “Just got this. Supposed to be a relic.”

Comment: That's the one, I found it difficult to search for the word "cat" online, but i knew that was his name.

Comment: Glad I could help. I searched for "mining colony cat emerald earring book sci-fi" which led me to the book *Psion* (the first in the series).

Comment: Clearly it's all in how you search, it would seem you have the gift, thanks again.

Answer (score 6):

Might be Joan D. Vinge's *Cat* series. The books are: Psion, Catspaw, and Dreamfall. The series premise is that there are human-alien hybrids that have telepathy to varying degrees. These "Psions" are treated, well, like pre-civil rights-era Blacks in America. The first book, Psion, is set on a mining colony where the Psions are being used as slave labor. The main character, Cat, gets caught in the middle of a violent conflict between Psions and the "regular" Human coprporate-government. In the second book, Catspaw, Cat is hired by an insanely rich corporate family as an extra security measure (because of his telepathy).

I don't see much about an earring, 'cept for this in the second book (Catspaw):

> As I passed the bathroom mirror, a sudden flash of green caught my
>   eye. I stopped, looking at myself, turning my head - saw the light wink
>   again. My ear. I reached up, touching it, with a slow smile starting.
>   There was an earring in my ear, one I’ d never seen before. Green
>   glass, catching the light when I moved, like a cat’s eye. I knew I
>   hadn’t put it there… I figured I knew who had. I stuck a drug patch
>   behind my ear, and went out of the room.

later:

> “That earring. I wouldn’t wear it again, if I were you. Particularly
>   not around Charon.”
>
> My hand went to my ear, covering it, protecting it. “Why not?” Not
>   quite able to keep all the tension out of my voice. “It’s only a piece
>   of glass.”
>
> His lips pulled up. “It’s an emerald, you fool.”
>
> I stared at him, still touching my ear. “What-?” He’d scanned its
>   density just by looking at me.
>
> He looked at me now, and shook his head again. “You’re lying about
>   where you got it, too. It carries a taMing registry code; it belongs
>   to Lady Lazuli.”
>
> My hand dropped to my side. I turned and went out the door. I felt his
>   eyes following my back as I crossed the endless, lifeless room beyond.

It's so obviously out of his price range, it causes a fair amount of trouble.